# tfs api get files by extension

Tags: tfs

Is this correct?  When calling method `GetItems()` on this item spec it is not returning anything even though I do indeed have .cs files in that directory (in a couple folders deep)

```
[0] = {ItemSpec instance 12345678
  Item: $/HelloWorld/Branches/Main/*.cs
  RecursionType: Full
  DeletionId: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was elsewhere (in that the default collection was still specified rather than the collection I wished to look into).

Nevertheless, you CAN utilize patterns such as *.cs, *.txt etc and retrieve only files matching those extensions.